# list created str in range other list

Tags: python

i have a list like below:

```
[3,2,4,5]
```

and i want a list like below:

```
[['1','2','3'],['1','2'],['1','2','3','4'],['1','2','3','4','5']]
```

i mean i want to have a list that is created by the count of another list.
I want to iterate each with string.

how can i write it in python

i tried this code:

```
    for i,val in enumerate(list_mf_input):
        self.eachMembership.append([])
        for value in range(1, val+1):
            self.eachMembership.append([value])
```

Comment: Why `enumerate()` - you are never using `i`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `range` with `list`, and list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [3, 2, 4, 5]
>>> [list(range(1, x+1)) for x in a]
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

And to make all strings, add `map` with `str`:

```
>>>[list(map(str, range(1, x+1))) for x in a]
[['1', '2', '3'], ['1', '2'], ['1', '2', '3', '4'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']]
```

Comment: 1up for the speed

Comment: it send this error TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: Did you name your list `list`?

Answer (score 1):

try this code. I tried to make as easy as possible

```
lol=[3,2,4,5]
ans=[]
temp=[]
for i in lol:
    for j in range(1,i+1):
        temp.append(j)
    ans.append(temp)
    temp=[]
print(ans)
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Just move `temp=[]` to just after the `for i ...` then you can eliminate the outer `temp=[]`